# set cookie in java

Tags: java, javascript, browser

I am developing a web browser in java . 
To parse the HTML page into a DOM document 
then to render it I use an API  "cobra" . But 
it is not cookie enabled . So I have to manage it 
by myself. I create a class that can collect cookie 
from web-page . That is not my problem. But the 
problem is that when I click in log-in button 
of a website that need cookie to log-in like 
facebook (because log-in button is a java-script 
button so my browser has to implement the
 java-script function .But that API can also handle 
java-script function) as an event of button clicking 
the API internally create a connection to server and 
send the data. But I need to create that connection to 
the server for setting cookie. Because the API internally create the URL-Connection ( The API has no method 
to set property to URL-Connection ) .So how can I send cookie 
with URL-connection . If you have any better idea that
can solve my crisis plz share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not posted any code that makes a request, but I think what you need to do is this:

```
URLConnection conn = you get a connection from somewhere...;
...
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "cookieName=cookieValue");
...
```

[See here for more details](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/cookie_support.html), Also you may want to [research cookies](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/) a bit to make sure your implementation is secure and works.

Also, remember that javascript is allowed access to cookies through `document.cookie`.

Comment: I know how to set cookie property . That is not my problem . My problem is how can I know when the button is clicked because when button is clicked I have to create URL-connection .then I can use setProperty  method.